# TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html

here is my HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="JS/SignUp.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="subContainer">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my JavaScript code

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("subContainer");
x[0].innerHTML = "Hello World!";
```

but i am getting error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script is running before the elements are added to DOM. Either wait for [DOM content load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) or add `script` tag at the end of `body`.

Comment: ohh thank you sir how i am not getting it 

thank you so much sir

Comment: No issues. Consider upvoting/accepting is this helps you.

Comment: yeah sir i am just doing work  at night 12 but getting this error so  i shutdown after wasting my time 25min    thnak you so much for your faster answer